# How to make arrow pointing same direction as line in Jetpack Compose Canvas

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I made a coordinate system with canvas, i also want to make an arrow (like vector) pointing in some direction. My approach to make the arrow is to draw a line then make a triangle using path. The path I specified is hardcoded, this makes arrow point at fixed direction.

My drawVector function :

```
fun DrawScope.drawVector(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    parentSize: Size,
    sizeOfGrid: Size,
    directions: Pair<Int, Int>, // (2, 1) -> move x-axis 2 grid right, move y-axis 1 grid up
) {
    val originX = parentSize.width / 2f
    val originY = parentSize.height / 2f

    drawLine(
        color = Color.Green,
        start = Offset(x = originX, y = originY),
        end = Offset(
            x = originX + directions.first * sizeOfGrid.width,
            y = originY + -(directions.second) * sizeOfGrid.height
        ),
        strokeWidth = 10f
    )

    // Have to make directions.second negative to adjust with canvas coordinate system
    val arrowPath = Path()
    arrowPath.moveTo(
        x = (originX + directions.first * sizeOfGrid.width) - 20f,
        y = (originY + -(directions.second) * sizeOfGrid.height) - 20f
    )
    arrowPath.lineTo(
        x = (originX + directions.first * sizeOfGrid.width) + 20f,
        y = (originY + -(directions.second) * sizeOfGrid.height) + 20f
    )
    arrowPath.lineTo(
        x = (originX + directions.first * sizeOfGrid.width) + 20f,
        y = (originY + -(directions.second) * sizeOfGrid.height) - 20f
    )
    arrowPath.close()
    drawPath(arrowPath, color = Color.Green)
}
```

[image]

Anyone got an idea?